# How to change the background to a different image every time the screen changes

Tags: processing

I am trying to find how to change the background to a different image every time the screen changes. A bit of context: I am trying to make a quiz game, and every time I click on an answer, the screen change. With the screen changing to a different question, I want to change the background as well. There will be 10 questions so I have 10 images.

So far, I am just mapping out the process on paper, basically, how should I tackle it step by step, but I am stuck on this one. Just looking for some orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a `PImage` for each background:

```
PImage background1;
PImage background2;
...
```

Then in draw, depending on the question, you can say which image to draw through a switch statement:

```
switch (question)
{
    case 1 -> image(background1, 0, 0);
    case 2 -> image(background2, 0, 0);
    ...
}
```

And if you want, you can have questions be objects which store all the necessary information including its own background.

```
class Question
{
   PImage background;
   String message;
    
   void draw()
   {
       image(background, 0, 0);
       text(message, 100, 100);
   }
}

@Override
public void draw() // draw loop
{
    currentQuestion.draw();
}
```

Where `currentQuestion` is the currently "selected" question in an array/list.

This way when you supposedly change questions, the image drawn by `draw()` in `Question` will change too.